# Automatic Filling & Web Post of (Website Form) using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have this webpage ( http://reg.nid-moi.gov.iq/registersubmit ) and it contains a form that I would like to auto fill the data of the form by posting function according to the following function parameter in javascript code
and source code of the page as the following :
Webpage Sourcecode Script :
[webpage sourcecode script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riv9f.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BA5O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it.

```
<script>
// if you want to fill form on button click
function setInitailFormData(){
//getting the element you want to fill
 var inputName = document.getElementsById('inputName');
//setting up the value
 inputName.value = "Gohan"
}
//if you want to fill on component mount
window.onload = function setInitailFormData(){
//getting the element you want to fill
 var inputName = document.getElementsById('inputName');
//setting up the value
 inputName.value = "Gohan"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , but the function contain a token key and json parameter :
<form role="form" action="http://reg.nid-moi.gov.iq/codeverficationsubmit" onsubmit="submitbtn.disabled = true; return true;" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="RognpkTX4R5Y1ZoXQN5BhzxUM7JrVkVBuWIxKjRN">

Comment: and the question is ? what do you want to do with it ?